# How to disable focussing on an element in IE10

Tags: accessibility, internet-explorer-10

We have a set of moving clouds (implemented using `div`s) in a home page of a web project. IE 10 focus on these elements with tabs even though they are not focus enabled elements (no tab index).

Comment: Can you add a code sample, please?

Comment: The `<div>` might not have a tabindex but you could have an interactive element nested under it that allows focus.  As @stringy said, we need a code example

Answer (score 0):

Without a code sample, I'd purely be guessing.

Something to try is to set the div's tabindex to -1.

```
<div class="pretty-cloud" tabindex="-1" />
```

The other option is that there is an element inside these divs which is tab focussable. Try the trick above to make it so they aren't, if you still want to use that type of element.